# Est-ce que les gens utilisent « Y a ouiq' » en français ?

Tags: sens, traduction, anglais, usage

J'écoutais la chanson « 200k » de Tiakola quand j'ai entendu « Y a ouiq' » comme paroles.  Le français est ma deuxième langue, alors j'ai demandé à mon père et à mes cousins ​​ce que cela signifiait (puisque le français est leur langue maternelle) et ils ont répondu qu'ils ne savaient pas.

Le clip vidéo disait que cela signifiait (en anglais) « What's up », mais Google Translate a une réponse différente; « Yes there is ».

Je comprends que le rap français utilise beaucoup d'argot donc je voulais savoir à quel point cette expression est courante et comment un Français réagirait si je disais « Y a ouiq' ».

---

I was listening to Tiakola's song "200k" when I heard « Y a ouiq' » as a lyric. French is my second language, so I asked my father and cousins what it meant (as french is their first language) and they said they didn't know. The music video said it meant (in english) « What's up » but Google Translate has a different answer; « Yes there is ». I understand French rap uses a lot of slang so I wanted to know how common this expression is and how a french person would respond if I said " Y a ouiq' ".

Comment: Personnellement je n'ai jamais entendu cette expression et je n'ai aucune idée de ce qu'elle peut bien vouloir dire, mais je suis loin d'être un amateur de rap !

Comment: Moi idem, jamais entendu,  argot des banlieues ? emprunt phonétique à l'anglais (plusieurs mots anglais dans le texte) ? On peut peut-être isoler *ouiq'* , *y a* pouvant être « il y a », S'il n'y avait apostrophe, j'aurais peut-être dit que  *ouiq'* pourrait être « quoi » ( → y a quoi ?, il se passe quoi ?), mais dans ce cas pourquoi cette apostrophe ?

Answer (score 6):

Il dit, en verlan, *Y'a wak ?* (**Y'a quoi ?**), ce qui correspond bien à ***What's up?***

c.f. Nawak/[Portnawak](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/portnawak).

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RjgCO8lI1M8

Answer (score 5):

Le lien YT que donne jlliagre déroule le texte en même temps que le rap. L'auteur orthographie "y a oi-qu'" (et non "y a ouiq'") et jlliagre, "y'a wak". Dans l'un et l'autre cas c'est bien  "y a quoi" en verlan, qui est un néologisme.

La forme canonique pour ma génération est "quoi de neuf?", "comment va?" ou "ça gaze?"; réponse possible: "Boh, ça gazouille". P. ex., la doublure française de Bugs Bunny à la TV traduisait "Em... Wha's up, Doc?" par "Euh... Quoi de neuf, docteur?".

Je ne crois pas que "y a ouiq" ou "y a wik" soit interprétable. Peut-être J. Dujardin pourrait-il tranformer "y a [que pouic](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/que_pouic)" en "y a wikep" en réponse à "y a wak?", dans un hypothétique *[OSS 117](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OSS_117:_Cairo,_Nest_of_Spies) à La Courneuve*.

Answer (score 3):

As the others said, it's verlan for "*y'a quoi*". It doesn't have a single spelling. You can find "*oi-qu*", "*wak*" among other variations.

To answer your main question: no, I wouldn't say "*y'a wak*" is a common expression. It's a rare verlan used to add variety in a song, not a widespread phrase. Sometimes rappers use rare slang that is understood but not common in natural French.

"*Y'a quoi*" is much more common though.

---

About the meaning, I wouldn't say it means strictly "what's up". Though it can be used in that sense, its meaning is close to "what's going on" or "what is it" (as "*y'a quoi*" is a looser form of "*qu'est-ce qu'il y a*"). It can be used when meeting up with friends, to ask "what's up", "what's popping", but also in other contexts. Saying it to someone that's not your friend can mean something like "you got a problem?" or "you got anything to say?".